# Convert separate array deep keys to required type (array or object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, hierarchy

How we can convert only 'items' (object type) keys to array type:

```
var arr = [{
  "title": "Custom title",
  "id": "id1",
  "icon": "fa fa-reorder",
  "other": {
    "3991": {
      "title": "Some title",
      "link": "#",
      "icon": "",
      "items": {
        "3992": {
          "title": "Some title",
          "link": "#",
          "icon": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "3993": {
      "title": "Some title",
      "link": "#",
      "icon": ""
    }
  }
}];
```

To:

```
var arr = [{
  "title": "Custom title",
  "id": "id1",
  "icon": "fa fa-reorder",
  "other": {
    "3991": {
      "title": "Some title",
      "link": "#",
      "icon": "",
      "items": [{
          "title": "Some title",
          "link": "#",
          "icon": ""
        }]
    },
    "3993": {
      "title": "Some title",
      "link": "#",
      "icon": ""
    }
  }
}];
```

I need separatly choose every time to what type change specified key. I've searched for some array walkers, but with no success.

Example:

```
var newArr = change_key_type({
 'arr' : arr,
 'key' : 'items',
 'type' : 'array'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over and build a new array for all `items`.

```js
function walk(a) {
    typeof a === 'object' && Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === 'items' && typeof a.items === 'object') {
            a.items = Object.keys(a.items).map(function (k) {
                walk(a.items[k]);
                return a.items[k];
            });
            return;
        }
        walk(a[k]);
    });
}

var arr = [{ "title": "Custom title", "id": "id1", "icon": "fa fa-reorder", "other": { "3991": { "title": "Some title", "link": "#", "icon": "", "items": { "3992": { "title": "Some title", "link": "#", "icon": "" } } }, "3993": { "title": "Some title", "link": "#", "icon": "" } } }];

arr.forEach(walk);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for new ideas. But when items key not exist in first level, then process of walking will be stoped...

Comment: Main problem exist exactly in this. Maybe You have some ideas how to solve it?

Comment: i do not know you data structure, or where to expect some keys for combining it to an array.